Is it possible to create non-tail recursive reverse list function in Scheme?
I was experimenting with reversing a list in Scheme. I came up with this code:
(define (rev lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (result '()))
    (if (null? lst)
        result
        (loop (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) result)))))

It works fine, but I wanted to see (as an experiment) if I can rewrite this as non-TCO, since Non TCO are usually simpler to write.
I did a dump rearrangement to get rid of the accumulator:
(define (rev lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (car lst) (rev (cdr lst)))))

But this one just copy the list, is there an easy way to create non TCO recursive function that reverse a list?
I was asking ChatGPT, and he shows me the code that use append that was correct. But can you do this without append that will traverse the list?
This may be a silly question, but I have no idea if it's possible, that's why I'm asking.
While writing this question, I came up with a more fundamental one. Does TCO algorithm with an accumulator always create list in reverse and non-TCO always in same order? Or maybe you can create an algorithm that break this rule. So far, I always use (revese result) when operating on lists when using accumulator.

Your second function isn't even recursing.

Since it doesn't recurse, the tail of the result is the same list as the original list. It's only copying the first cons.

@Barmar yes I forget to update the code to actually use (rev (cdr lst)).

Lists are created last to first, but iterated first to last. Thus iterating and consing reverses the list. Making it less effective a strange request when there are so many times we want the same order but rather have tail recursion ☺️ reason why non tco ends up being in order is because the arguments are evaluated before the application, thus the tail is made first

@Sylwester ? (cons (car lst) (rev (cdr lst))) results in the non-reversed order of result regardless of order of evaluation.  it would be "tail-recursive" under lazy evaluation (but not-tail under just normal order), but the order would still be the same.

@WillNess Not regardless since both operands needs to be evaluated before application (when forced in lazy/normal order)

Whatever the order, the end result is the same: a cons cell with a car, and a cdr. We are talking the order of result, not the order in which it is build. @Sylwester

@WillNess order of build and result is related. Thats my point. To get in order you need to cons the last pair first, like a recursive solution facilitates

@Sylwester it doesn't matter if you start by putting B into CDR and then put A into the CAR, or if you put A into the CAR and then put B into CDR; the A is still in the CAR and B in the CDR. this is my point, and I don't understand how yours could be true.

@WillNess I'm not taling about same level order, which is irrelevant. In (let ((a expr1)) (let ((b expr2)) ...)) expr1 is always evaluated before expr2 since a needs to be determined before the body. Same with (cons a b). Both a and b needs to be fully evaluated before cons is applied. b will be the tail recursion and thus consed before and thus created from last to first element. In (cons (car lst) (rev (cdr lst))), the (rev (cdr lst)) is fully evaluated before cons is applied  and thus the tail is created first

There's a Python implementation here and this is a translation to Scheme:
(define (rev lst)
  (if (or (null? lst) (null? (cdr lst)))
      lst
      (let ((new-lst (rev (cdr lst))))
        (set-cdr! (cdr lst) lst)
        (set-cdr! lst '())
        new-lst)))


Thanks, but specifically asked to not have append. And the second throw an error: Expecting pair got nil in expression set-cdr!

Fixed it. (cdr new-lst) should have been (cdr lst).

Thanks, can delete the append example? This is what chagGPT given me, and I was asking for code without append because the code iterate over list multiple times. Append will need to traverse the list to append element at the end. So this is not O(n).

That's why I said it's not efficient. It's O(n^2)./

I said append is O(n). Since it calls it n times, that makes the algorithm O(n^2).

BTW, you could have found the page I translated by googling "recursive list reverse algorithm" just like I did.

That won't work very well with schemes where a literal list is made out of immutable pairs - (rev '(1 2 3)) gives an error with gauche and outright segfaults guile for example.

Right, this is an in-place reverse (like CL nreverse).

under (an old version of) #lang r5rs in Racket, (let ((x (list 1 2 3))) (display (list (rev x) x))) produces ((3 2 1) (1)). In CLisp, (let ((x (list 1 2 3))) (list (nreverse x) x)) produces ((3 2 1) (3 2 1)).

@WillNess The CL specification is agnostic about the precise way that the original list is reused in the result. It can relink the cdrs (as my code does) or it can swap the cars (as it would for a vector). CLisp is apparently doing the latter.

Unfortunately, Barmar's adaptation of Python code will fail badly when passed a literal list in many Scheme implementations where they're immutable; for example with Gauche, (rev '(1 2 3)) errors out with: *** ERROR: attempt to mutate cdr of an immutable pair (3) with (2 3) ((rev (list 1 2 3)) works fine, though, because list always uses mutable pairs). And if you pass it a variable holding a list, it changes that original list:
> (define x (list 1 2 3))
> (rev x)
(3 2 1)
> x
(1)

Personally, none of that is desirable behavior (though mutating the original argument would be okay if it was called rev! along the lines of SRFI-1 conventions). The following is a non-tail-recursive version that always builds the reversed list out of new pairs instead of reusing existing ones, without using append. It uses a helper function that returns a reversed sublist and the last pair of the list in one go, to have a O(N) runtime complexity:
(define (rev lst)
  (define (helper lst) ; (length lst) >= 1
    (if (null? (cdr lst))
        (let ((single-elem (list (car lst))))
          (values single-elem single-elem))
        (let-values (((reversed last) (helper (cdr lst)))
                     ((new-last) (list (car lst))))
          (set-cdr! last new-last)
          (values reversed new-last))))
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (let-values (((reversed _) (helper lst))) reversed)))


I actually found it uncomfortable to write a function that's trivial with tail recursion in a non-tail manner. Also trivial with higher order functions - (fold cons '() the-list)

Thanks, this works, but for my simple experiment I think that Barmar's solution is just fine. But it's good to know abut the problem it gives and the proper solution.

under #lang r5rs in an old version of Racket, Barmar's code displays ((3 2 1) (1)) for (let ((x (list 1 2 3))) (display (list (rev x) x))), whereas the code in this answer correctly shows ((3 2 1) (1 2 3)). ( although there's no let-values in r5rs, it is trivial to re-write in terms of call-with-values, of course. )

@WillNess I assume people are using R7RS or R6RS these days when a particular Scheme implementation or standard isn't explicitly mentioned.

the main point was that your code works correctly for the given input. :) I prefer r5rs for these snippets on SO because the code usually just works. In r6rs one needs an import statement, potentially baffling for a casual reader just starting learning "Lisp."

Recursion is a tool that is intended to ease our reasoning, to ease our coming up with an answer.
Specifically, we do this by assuming we've already written the solution!
(define (rev0 lst)
  (rev0 lst))

... well, this of course does not do much good, but we can remedy this by always making sure we call it on strictly smaller lists than the input. This will guarantee an empty list will eventually be encountered, and if we handle it in a  special, non-recursive way, we'll guarantee the termination of the whole call chain:
(define (rev lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lst)       lst)
    ((null? (cdr lst)) lst)   ;; this is also a simple case
    (else                     ;; here `lst` has at least 2 elts

Now, faced with a list which holds more than 1 element, we need a way to somehow divide it into shorter parts. The simplest is to somehow take one element out, and be left with a remaining list which is shorter by 1 than the original.
If we had pattern-matching to get the last element and the rest of list,
      ;;(with-list-pattern ([...pfx, x] lst)

we could get pfx that is guaranteed to be shorter than lst, so we are allowed to rev it, and put the last element x first in the result,
      ;;    (cons x (rev pfx)))

and that would be it: the last element of lst becomes the first of the result, and the rest of the result is the reversed prefix of lst:
     rev [a, b, c, d, ... x, y, z]
     [z, ...rev [a, b, c, d, ... x, y]]
     [z, ...[y, ...rev [a, b, c, d, ... x]]]
     [z,     y, ...rev [a, b, c, d, ... x] ]
     ..........
     [z,  y,  x, ... , d,  c,  b,  ...rev[a]]
     [z,  y,  x, ... , d,  c,  b,  ...[a]]
     [z,  y,  x, ... , d,  c,  b,      a ]

But, but, we do not have such patterns available to us in Scheme! I hear some older languages like SNOBOL and (a somewhat mystical) REFAL had (have?) such patterns, but in Scheme, we're stuck with the plain (CAR . CDR) pattern:
      (let* ((a (car lst))        ; one elt
             (d (cdr lst))        ; at least one elt

so now this d is lst's suffix, one-shorter than the original lst. We can reverse it, now,
             (dr (rev d))         ; at least one elt

and, then, what? The only other thing we can do now is to split up this dr:
             (dra (car dr))       ; one elt
             (drd (cdr dr))       ; 0 or more elts

and, ... is it any good? What is this dra? It's the last element of d, and this means, that it is the last element of lst! So then, we've got our first element of the result, dra, and only need to find the rest of it next.
So what do we have at our disposal? It's drd, the suffix of the reversed suffix of lst. Prepending the original first element a to it (*) gives us that prefix-before-last-element pfx we saw in that imaginary pattern above:
             (pfx (cons a drd)))     ; see (*) below

and since this pfx is 1-shorter than lst, we're allowed to just call our rev on it and be done with it!
         (cons dra (rev pfx))))))


(*)  is not quite true, and can be fixed with the same trick of using the same function we are still defining and haven't finished defining yet! It is enough to know that we will finish defining it, at some point -- our definitions are finite, after all.
See also: How to reverse the order of elements of a list in Scheme

Thanks, the link at the end is actually want i was looking for.
